# Searching a text in range based on a cell

Tags: excel

I have the following query for a formula in excel:
A1 = red;
A2 = yellow

From B2:Z2 somewhere there I have the text "blue"

How to create a formula that based on what I have in column A to check whether there is the text "blue" in the given range.
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "Based on what I have in Column A". You state you have `red` and `yellow` in Column A. How does that related to `Blue` being somewhere in `B2:Z2`. If you just want to know if `blue` is in that range you can do `=countif(B2:Z2, "blue")>0` which will return `True` or `False`.

Comment: I did not explain correctly, you are right. I have two tables with data. In the first one is
Column A - different colours - let's say -> yellow and red
against them somewhere is written or not the text "blue"
In the second table based on what the data in column A - as I will have the same data in the second table, I want to check whether the text blue exists if I pick up yellow from the second table

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a list of colors in column A.
In row 1 columns B-Z you have a list of random words.
Shift A down by one row so that your list starts at A2.

```
=IF(A2<>"",IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(C5,$B$2:$Z$2,1,FALSE)),"Found","Not Found"),"")
```

Then drag down.

If the color in A* is within the B2:Z2 range then it returns "Found". If the color in A* is not found it returns "Not Found".

Is this what you were wanting?